# how to make single object from an object array that has common key:value pair

Tags: javascript

I have some data

```
var list =[{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.58},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", radiation: 829.03},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", relativehumidity: 0.78},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", temperature: 20.24},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", winddirection: 56.43},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", windgusts: 3.78},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", windspeed: 1.73},

{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.5},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", radiation: 739.98},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", relativehumidity: 0.74},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", temperature: 20.82},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", winddirection: 52.83},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", windgusts: 2.95},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", windspeed: 1.54}]
```

and I would like to transform it to

```
var list =[
   { 
    date: '2019-09-27T08:00',
    atmosphericpressure: 80.58,
    lightningdistance: 0,
    lightningevents: 0,
    precipitation: 0,
    radiation: 829.03,
    relativehumidity: 0.78,
    temperature: 20.24,
    winddirection: 56.43,
    windgusts: 3.78,
    windspeed: 1.73
},
{
date: '2019-09-27T09:00',
    atmosphericpressure: 80.5,
    lightningdistance: 0,
    lightningevents: 0,
    precipitation: 0,
    radiation: 739.98,
    relativehumidity: 0.74,
    temperature: 22.82,
    winddirection: 52.83,
    windgusts: 2.95,
    windspeed: 1.54
}
]
```

I have have tried using filters like so

```
let temp=[]
   let result = list.filter(obj => {
  if(obj.date === '2019-09-27T09:00'){
   let group= {
     date:obj.date,
    atmosphericpressure:obj.atmosphericpressure,
    lightningdistance:obj.lightningdistance,
    lightningevents:obj.lightningevents,
    precipitation:obj.precipitation,
    radiation:obj.radiation,
    relativehumidity:obj.relativehumidity,
    temperature:obj.temperature,
    winddirection:obj.winddirection,
    windgusts:obj.windgusts,
    windspeed:obj.windspeed
    }
    temp.push(group)
  }
})

console.log(temp)
```

but the result is not as I would like, I get the following

```
[
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": 80.5,
    "lightningdistance": undefined,
    "lightningevents": undefined,
    "precipitation": undefined,
    "radiation": undefined,
    "relativehumidity": undefined,
    "temperature": undefined,
    "winddirection": undefined,
    "windgusts": undefined,
    "windspeed": undefined
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": undefined,
    "lightningdistance": 0,
    "lightningevents": undefined,
    "precipitation": undefined,
    "radiation": undefined,
    "relativehumidity": undefined,
    "temperature": undefined,
    "winddirection": undefined,
    "windgusts": undefined,
    "windspeed": undefined
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": undefined,
    "lightningdistance": undefined,
    "lightningevents": 0,
    "precipitation": undefined,
    "radiation": undefined,
    "relativehumidity": undefined,
    "temperature": undefined,
    "winddirection": undefined,
    "windgusts": undefined,
    "windspeed": undefined
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": undefined,
    "lightningdistance": undefined,
    "lightningevents": undefined,
    "precipitation": 0,
    "radiation": undefined,
    "relativehumidity": undefined,
    "temperature": undefined,
    "winddirection": undefined,
    "windgusts": undefined,
    "windspeed": undefined
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": undefined,
    "lightningdistance": undefined,
    "lightningevents": undefined,
    "precipitation": undefined,
    "radiation": 739.98,
    "relativehumidity": undefined,
    "temperature": undefined,
    "winddirection": undefined,
    "windgusts": undefined,
    "windspeed": undefined
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": undefined,
    "lightningdistance": undefined,
    "lightningevents": undefined,
    "precipitation": undefined,
    "radiation": undefined,
    "relativehumidity": 0.74,
    "temperature": undefined,
    "winddirection": undefined,
    "windgusts": undefined,
    "windspeed": undefined
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": undefined,
    "lightningdistance": undefined,
    "lightningevents": undefined,
    "precipitation": undefined,
    "radiation": undefined,
    "relativehumidity": undefined,
    "temperature": 20.82,
    "winddirection": undefined,
    "windgusts": undefined,
    "windspeed": undefined
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": undefined,
    "lightningdistance": undefined,
    "lightningevents": undefined,
    "precipitation": undefined,
    "radiation": undefined,
    "relativehumidity": undefined,
    "temperature": undefined,
    "winddirection": 52.83,
    "windgusts": undefined,
    "windspeed": undefined
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": undefined,
    "lightningdistance": undefined,
    "lightningevents": undefined,
    "precipitation": undefined,
    "radiation": undefined,
    "relativehumidity": undefined,
    "temperature": undefined,
    "winddirection": undefined,
    "windgusts": 2.95,
    "windspeed": undefined
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-27T09:00",
    "atmosphericpressure": undefined,
    "lightningdistance": undefined,
    "lightningevents": undefined,
    "precipitation": undefined,
    "radiation": undefined,
    "relativehumidity": undefined,
    "temperature": undefined,
    "winddirection": undefined,
    "windgusts": undefined,
    "windspeed": 1.54
  }
]
```

This is my code, please run to see results and how It can be made to as I would like

```js
var list = [{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.58},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", radiation: 829.03},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", relativehumidity: 0.78},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", temperature: 20.24},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", winddirection: 56.43},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", windgusts: 3.78},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", windspeed: 1.73},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.5},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", radiation: 739.98},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", relativehumidity: 0.74},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", temperature: 20.82},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", winddirection: 52.83},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", windgusts: 2.95},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", windspeed: 1.54},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.37},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", radiation: 662.45},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", relativehumidity: 0.69},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", temperature: 21.64},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", winddirection: 68.55},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", windgusts: 2.59},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", windspeed: 1.17},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.3},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", radiation: 292.93},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", relativehumidity: 0.66},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", temperature: 21.31},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", winddirection: 47.26},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", windgusts: 2.74},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", windspeed: 1.24},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.24},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", radiation: 168.85},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", relativehumidity: 0.65},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", temperature: 21.23},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", winddirection: 46.44},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", windgusts: 1.77},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", windspeed: 0.87},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.22},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", radiation: 133.87},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", relativehumidity: 0.65},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", temperature: 20.89},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", winddirection: 44.6},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", windgusts: 1.7},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", windspeed: 1.02},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.25},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", radiation: 79.42},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", relativehumidity: 0.65},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", temperature: 20.56},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", winddirection: 48.5},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", windgusts: 1.79},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", windspeed: 0.95},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.3},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", radiation: 16.2},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", relativehumidity: 0.7},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", temperature: 19.46},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", winddirection: 352.4},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", windgusts: 0.68},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", windspeed: 0.42},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.37},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", radiation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", relativehumidity: 0.77},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", temperature: 18.43},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", winddirection: 333.37},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", windgusts: 1.73},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", windspeed: 0.89},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.41},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", radiation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", relativehumidity: 0.85},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", temperature: 17.42},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", winddirection: 353.25},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", windgusts: 0.94},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", windspeed: 0.46}
];
  let temp=[]
   let result = list.filter(obj => {
  if(obj.date === '2019-09-27T09:00'){
   let group= {
     date:obj.date,
    atmosphericpressure:obj.atmosphericpressure,
    lightningdistance:obj.lightningdistance,
    lightningevents:obj.lightningevents,
    precipitation:obj.precipitation,
    radiation:obj.radiation,
    relativehumidity:obj.relativehumidity,
    temperature:obj.temperature,
    winddirection:obj.winddirection,
    windgusts:obj.windgusts,
    windspeed:obj.windspeed
    }
    temp.push(group)
  }
})

console.log(temp)
```

I would really need some insights on how to achieve this, anyone please help. I have also attached a snipped of my current implementation so that it becomes easy to see what I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array forEach to achieve what you want

```js
var list =[{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.58},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", radiation: 829.03},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", relativehumidity: 0.78},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", temperature: 20.24},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", winddirection: 56.43},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", windgusts: 3.78},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", windspeed: 1.73},

{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.5},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", radiation: 739.98},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", relativehumidity: 0.74},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", temperature: 20.82},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", winddirection: 52.83},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", windgusts: 2.95},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", windspeed: 1.54}]

const result = [];
list.forEach(i => {
  let x = result.find(r => r.date === i.date);
  if(x) {
    Object.assign(x, i);
  } else {
    result.push(i);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That was the method I was trying to remember.. I couldn't find it around so I took the long way to do it. A wee bit salty, lol.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I like it because It can work dynamically. I am pulling Tahmo weather data and some fields may change depending on station

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem :

You're assigning values to all object properties at every iteration. In each iteration, you'll get value of single property. All other values will be undefined. So the remaining values will be overwritten with undefined every time.

#### The workaround

Instead of manually assigning to all values, use `temp[index][Object.keys(obj)[1]] = Object.values[obj][1])`

I used a function to reduce some codes.

#### The code:

```
let temp=[];
function addData(pos,obj){ 
// a function to add the property to object at given position
  temp[pos][Object.keys(obj)[1]] = Object.values(obj)[1];
}
list.forEach((o) => { // Initialize the array with available dates
  if(!temp.find((d)=> d.date==o.date)){
    temp.push({"date":o.date});
  }
});
list.forEach((o) => { // Looping through each object
 temp.forEach((d) => { // looping through temp to find the position in temp
  if(o.date == d.date){
    window.addData(temp.indexOf(d),o);
  }
 }); 
});
console.log(temp)
```

```js
var list = [{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.58},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", radiation: 829.03},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", relativehumidity: 0.78},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", temperature: 20.24},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", winddirection: 56.43},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", windgusts: 3.78},
{date: "2019-09-27T08:00", windspeed: 1.73},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.5},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", radiation: 739.98},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", relativehumidity: 0.74},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", temperature: 20.82},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", winddirection: 52.83},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", windgusts: 2.95},
{date: "2019-09-27T09:00", windspeed: 1.54},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.37},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", radiation: 662.45},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", relativehumidity: 0.69},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", temperature: 21.64},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", winddirection: 68.55},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", windgusts: 2.59},
{date: "2019-09-27T10:00", windspeed: 1.17},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.3},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", radiation: 292.93},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", relativehumidity: 0.66},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", temperature: 21.31},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", winddirection: 47.26},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", windgusts: 2.74},
{date: "2019-09-27T11:00", windspeed: 1.24},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.24},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", radiation: 168.85},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", relativehumidity: 0.65},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", temperature: 21.23},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", winddirection: 46.44},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", windgusts: 1.77},
{date: "2019-09-27T12:00", windspeed: 0.87},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.22},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", radiation: 133.87},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", relativehumidity: 0.65},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", temperature: 20.89},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", winddirection: 44.6},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", windgusts: 1.7},
{date: "2019-09-27T13:00", windspeed: 1.02},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.25},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", radiation: 79.42},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", relativehumidity: 0.65},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", temperature: 20.56},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", winddirection: 48.5},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", windgusts: 1.79},
{date: "2019-09-27T14:00", windspeed: 0.95},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.3},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", radiation: 16.2},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", relativehumidity: 0.7},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", temperature: 19.46},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", winddirection: 352.4},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", windgusts: 0.68},
{date: "2019-09-27T15:00", windspeed: 0.42},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.37},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", radiation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", relativehumidity: 0.77},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", temperature: 18.43},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", winddirection: 333.37},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", windgusts: 1.73},
{date: "2019-09-27T16:00", windspeed: 0.89},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", atmosphericpressure: 80.41},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", lightningdistance: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", lightningevents: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", precipitation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", radiation: 0},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", relativehumidity: 0.85},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", temperature: 17.42},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", winddirection: 353.25},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", windgusts: 0.94},
{date: "2019-09-27T17:00", windspeed: 0.46}
];
let temp=[];
function addData(pos,obj){
  temp[pos][Object.keys(obj)[1]] = Object.values(obj)[1];
}
list.forEach((o) => {
  if(!temp.find((d)=> d.date==o.date)){
    temp.push({"date":o.date});
  }
});
list.forEach((o) => {
 temp.forEach((d) => {
  if(o.date == d.date){
    window.addData(temp.indexOf(d),o);
  }
 }); 
});
console.log(temp)
```

Comment: so, you have to change the code every time the date changes?

Comment: @JaromandaX I was already editing the answer to add the info. I used them as constants here. But it can be changed easily. Pl wait

Comment: this also would work if I already have some kind of array with the dates. Thank you for the insight

Comment: @Barty updated the code to work with any date. anyway Jaromanada X's anwer is simpler than this.

Comment: yes, that is why I am accepting it, though now I know two ways of going about it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vweuhj69/)

I added in this code with some comments.

```
let newList = [];
let currKey = "";
let currObj = {};
list.forEach(function(e,i) {
    if(currKey != e.date) {//How we will identify
    currKey = e.date;
    if(i != 0) //Prevents empty first space
        newList[newList.length] = currObj; //Adds object to new list
    currObj = {}; //Gives new starting point
    currObj.date = e.date;
  }

  if(currKey == e.date) {
    Object.keys(e).forEach(function(prop) {
        if(e != 'date')
        currObj[prop] = e[prop]; //Copies over the value
    });
  }
    if(i == list.length-1)
    newList[newList.length] = currObj; //Adds last object to list
});

console.log(newList);
```

Comment: seen it also works well, Thank  you guys have saved me some agony

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = [{
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        atmosphericpressure: 80.58
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        lightningdistance: 0
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        lightningevents: 0
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        precipitation: 0
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        radiation: 829.03
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        relativehumidity: 0.78
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        temperature: 20.24
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        winddirection: 56.43
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        windgusts: 3.78
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T08:00",
        windspeed: 1.73
    },

    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        atmosphericpressure: 80.5
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        lightningdistance: 0
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        lightningevents: 0
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        precipitation: 0
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        radiation: 739.98
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        relativehumidity: 0.74
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        temperature: 20.82
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        winddirection: 52.83
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        windgusts: 2.95
    },
    {
        date: "2019-09-27T09:00",
        windspeed: 1.54
    }
]

let temp = []
let result = list.filter(obj => {
    let dateExist = temp.find(item => item.date && item.date === obj.date)
    let tempObj = {}
    if (!dateExist) {
        Object.keys(obj).map((key, i) => {
            tempObj[key] = obj[key]
        })
        temp.push(tempObj)
    } else {
        Object.keys(obj).map((key, i) => {
            dateExist[key] = obj[key]
        })
    }
})

console.log(temp)
```